# How to pass viewbag values in a foreach from view to controller on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my *ViewCart.cshtml* page showing the number of products which is added by the user and its displayed by a **foreachloop**.I want to **pass all these product ids** and **some formdata**(extra) on **form submit**.
as am newbie this is unknown for me that how to pass list of data.

**Viewcart.cshtml**

```
@foreach(var p in ViewBag.product)
{
    <tr class="rem1">
        <td class="invert">1</td>
        <td class="invert-image">
            <a href="single_product.html">
                <img src="@Url.Content(p.img)" alt=" " height="75" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="invert">
            <div class="quantity">
                <div class="quantity-select">
                    <div class="entry value-minus" id="minus">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="entry value" id="counter">1</div>
                    <div class="entry value-plus active" id="plus" onclick="func()">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="invert" onclick="as()">@p.mname</td>

        <td class="invert" id="prize">@p.mprize</td>
        <td class="invert">
            <div class="rem">
                <div class="close1"> </div>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**my modalclass**

```
 public class items
    {
        public int mid { get; set; }
        public string mtype { get; set;}
        public string mname{ get; set; }
        public string mcode{ get; set; }
        public string msize{ get; set; }
        public DateTime mdate{ get; set; }
        public string mctype{ get; set; }
        public string mdprize { get; set; }
        public string mprize{ get; set;}
        public string mstock{ get; set;}
        public string img1 { get; set; }
        public string img2 { get; set; }
        public string img3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you should use a view model instead ViewBag

Comment: @Kamran  thank you for ur response sir,Can u please suggest me an example.

Comment: @codeseeker What does your `ViewBag.product` look like? I mean can you show us the `Model` that is populates this `ViewBag`?

Comment: @ Rahul Sharma  i updated the code.please take a look sir

Comment: @codeseeker Can you show me your `Controller` code for `ViewCart`. I need to see what kind of `Model` you are sending to your `View`. Usually `ViewBag` is used to send data from the `Controller` to your `View` but for form handling purposes like in your scenario, `Model-Binding` is the best option .

Comment: @Rahul Sharma yes thnq sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is lengthy process Here is example of view model you can follow and modify according to your need.

```
public class CartViewModel
{
    public List<CartItemModel> CartItemList { get; set; }

    public decimal NetTotal { get; set; }
    public CartViewModel()
    {
        CartItemList = new List<CartItemModel>();
    }
}

public class CartItemModel
{
    public long CartId { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; } 
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductImage { get; set; }
    public string VariantName { get; set; }
    public string VariantGroup { get; set; }
    public short Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountedPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public bool IsPromotional { get; set; }
}
```

and in your view loop through on this view model